# How do I change cake recipes for cupcakes?

Tags: baking, cake, cupcakes

This is a three-part question:

- Which classes of cake are unsuitable for cupcakes?  Can I do angel food cake or pound cake?
- What changes do I need to make when converting a normal cake recipe for cupcakes?  Temperature or baking time changes?
- Roughly how many cupcakes should I expect from a recipe scaled for a 9x9 pan, a 9" springform pan, or a 12 cup Bundt pan?  *I'm not looking for precise counts, just a rough estimate to the nearest 5 cupcakes.*

Comment: I think the best cupcake I ever had was a tres leches cupcake complete dripping with milk and with whipped cream and strawberry on top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- I've not yet found a cake recipe which I could not use for cupcakes instead.
- I always change the baking time and only the baking time.  I rotate the tray of cuppies after about 7 minutes, and after another 7 minutes or so I use the "clean toothpick" method to see when they are done.
- It does vary greatly, but from most cake recipes, I expect to get 18-24 regular cupcakes, about 40 mini-cupcakes, or 9-12 large ("Texas") cupcakes.

Comment: This is generally my experience as well. :)

Answer (score 6):

For the cooking, reduce the time but keep the temperature the same as before. If the large tin took 30 mins, then the cupcake might just be 8 to 10 minutes. The other questions are too vague to answer. How many cupcakes will vary from recipe to recipe and some recipes require other changes to make them work. There's no single answer that can apply to everything. A bit of trial and error will be required or else be more specific in your question as to what cake type you wish to try.

Comment: Why is it a vague question how many cupcakes (standard size) I should get from a (standard size) cake pan?  Is there something different about how the cakes rise in a muffin pan?

Comment: I find that I can use the same recipe (for a cake) as cupcakes multiple times and get different numbers of cupcakes each time, as it depends on how full you fill the tins, what size the muffin cups are, how precise you were in measuring, etc.

Comment: @Ashley: I've edited the question to be clearer.  I'm not trying to get an exact count (obviously that varies, as you said), just a rough guess so I know if it'll fit in my cupcake pan.

Comment: @BobMcGee awesome, it makes more sense now, and I agree with KatieK, below.