# In what ways does the size of the baking pan matter while baking cakes?

Tags: baking, cake, pan

[Rose Levy's reviews](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0688044026) warn about using the ***right*** sized pans, and say that failing to do so will result in failure.

I have glass ware and silicon cups for baking cakes. I prefer to bake the cake material in cups so that it takes less time, etc.

So, what kind of precautions should be taken if the intention is to bake cakes in cups?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to bake the batter in cupcake forms instead of cake pans?

Comment: @KristinaLopez yes, exactly.

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15833/how-do-i-change-cake-recipes-for-cupcakes/15843 for information about adjusting a cake recipe for cupcakes. Be prepared to be flexible, as the author's directions may only work for the designed-size cake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right size is important, because baking times are designed for a specific batter thickness. If a recipe is meant for a 26 cm pan and you pour the whole batter in a 18 cm pan, it will be much thicker and the middle won't get done before the top burns. That is why high cakes are made by stacking layers, not by baking one high cake.

You can pour a batch of batter into multiple small cups and have it turn out all right as long as the height stays more or less the same as it would have been in the large pan. My advice is to calculate the area of the pan given in the recipe and the area of your silicone cups, so you can know how many cups to use. You don't have to be completely precise, for the average cake it is not too terrible if you have +-0.5 cm difference in batter height. If the difference is larger, you can still get good results, but you should adjust the baking time.

The resulting cupcakes will still have the thickness of the normal cake, or somewhat more if you use less cups and bake accordingly longer. I would advise against trying to bake high-rise muffins from normal cake recipes. Even a sponge cake recipe might need some adjustment of the amount of baking powder before working as a high muffin. Other types of cake, especially the more exotic ones (genoise, flourless cakes) are unlikely to bake well if you fill them into deep cups.

Comment: Actually, if it's not more than 10" across and 3" high, I bake one cake and split it multiple times.  Of course, you have to have deeper than normal cake pans for it and adjust the baking temperature down slightly.  (if you bake lots of thin cakes, they'll dome in the middle, and you loose a lot when leveling them)  If it's wider than 10", [you may want cake strips or a heating core](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/27516/67)

Answer (score 2):

All the boxed cake mixes I have used include instructions for baking cupcakes but in case you are just working off of a recipe, there are many good cupcake resources online now since cupcakes are a big fad here in the US.

Oven time and avoiding overbaking is my #1 tip.  I check for doneness starting at approx. 10-12 minutes, using a toothpick in the center of a cupcake.  If the toothpick comes out clean or with crumbs only, they are done.

Here is a link to a site with excellent tips for everything from pan choice and preparation to fun suggestions for fillings:

http://www.wilton.com/cupcakes/making-cupcakes/

Best of luck with your cupcakes!